# The method 'add' was called on null : Flutter, SQFlite

Tags: flutter, android-sqlite, sqflite

I am getting data from SQLite in flutter. When I try to convert the list of Map to list of Objects. It gives the error of

> The method 'add' was called on null

On debuging, it shows that it has data but still gives the error.

Here is my code

```
 List<Image> imagesList;
    if (imagesListMap != null) {
      imagesListMap.forEach((element) {
        imagesList.add(Image.FromDatabase(element));
      });
    }
```

And its the debugging screenshot

[image: SS of debug]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize the `List` like this before calling `add()` on it..

```
List<Image> imagesList = [];
```